# Kubuntu 16.04 how to start Xorg with listen tcp

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, remote-desktop

I tried all solutions I found in answers to similar questions, but nothing works.
I have Kubunt 16.04 and I want to connect from remote to the X-Server, NOT with ssh.
(ssh -X works, but the performance with direct redirect the DISPLAY is much better)
I have edit lightdm.conf to

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=thorsten
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
xserver-allow-tcp=true
xserver-command=X -listen tcp
```

but Xorg starts everytime with option -nolisten tcp.

So, what can I do?

Comment: since when does x have an option "listen"? As far as I know you use `-nolisten trans-type` to -disable- tcp. Otherwise it does listen to tcp.

Comment: cant find the option here ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/Xserver.1.html so that probaly wont fly what you are doing.